# Error on importing Seaborn on a Jupiter notebook on python3

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, seaborn

Maybe This is a simple question. While I run `import seaborn as sns` it returns me an error

> No module named 'seaborn'

instead if run:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages")
import seaborn as sns
```

I have no error. Why ? because I have python 2.7 and 3 and I'm using Jupyter notebook on python3. I used `pip install seaborn`, `pip3 install seaborn` and also `conda install seaborn`

How can I use just import seaborn as sns without add the full path ? 
The strange thing is that the notebook is running using anaconda, but in it's list of packages seaborn is present.

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that the python version with which you have installed seaborn differs from the one with which you are executing the script.

You can specify the python (and pip) version of the installation using:

```
python3 -m pip install seaborn
```

what installs the module using the pip installer of python3, and then executing the script using:

```
python3 script.py
```

---

**Edit**, thanks to [Wayne's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8508004/wayne) comment:

If you're inside a Jupyter notebook, run:

```
%pip install seaborn
```

or `!pip install seaborn` for Jupyter of version <= 7.2

Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: I want use it in a notebook not in a script, however your solution does not work

Comment: Try running `%pip install seaborn` in a cell in your notebook.

Comment: The newer, better way is `%pip install`, @ChristophSchranz. This new magic insures it installs to correct environment. There is also `%conda install` now. See [here](https://hub.packtpub.com/ipython-7-3-releases-with-conda-and-pip-magics-and-python-3-8-compatibility/) and discussion [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/11524).

Comment: @Wayne can you explain me exactly what are the differences between pip and conda ? Who Should I prefer ?

Comment: Here `pip` is most direct and general. I only brought up `conda` because a similar magic command was added same time and a lot of folks use the anaconda package management system. Disregard that if not pertinent.